# Where to find the MobileFirst adapter files in native iOS app created by MobileFirst?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a sample application with MobileFirst and deployed in iPhone. Now i am trying to find the adapter folder in native folder, which was implemented by MobileFirst. Where i can find it??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A MobileFirst Platform Foundation project is divided into 'two': Your application(s) and your adapter(s).

See the image below of a project created in MobileFirst Studio.

- There is the "MyProject" folder. It contains:
- An adapters folder, containing a "MyHTTPAdapter" folder - this is your adapter. You deploy it to the server.
- An apps folder, containing a "MyNativeiOSSDK" folder - this is the folder containing the iOS SDK files you need to copy into your Xcode project. You deploy it as well to the server.

Review the following tutorials to learn more...

- For MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/
- For MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/
- Adapters Overview: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/adapter-framework-overview/

[image]

Comment: I created that project with windows eclipse and Imported build  part in XCode, Now where i will find that adapters which was implemented in Eclipse. I will post my folder structure.

Comment: Again. The adapters are in the MobileFirst project located in **Eclipse**. You will not find them in your Xcode project. Look in Eclipse.